# Is there anyway to document S4 class and its constructor separately using Roxygen2

Tags: r, r-s4, roxygen2

I am trying to design a S4 class with my own initialization method and separately document them with Roxygen2. Assuming my class is defined as:

```
#' This is the classA
#' @name classA-class
#' @rdname classA-class
######## @aliases NULL
#' @exportClass classA
classA <- setClass(Class = "classA", slots = list(member = "ANY"))
```

With the initialization method:

```
#' This is the constructor
#' @name classA
#' @rdname classA
#' @export classA
setMethod("initialize", "classA", function(.Object, x) {
             .Object@member = x
             return(.Object)
         })
```

After compiling the package with Roxygen2. I got 2 .Rd files with 3 help page:

- classA-class: This is the classA
- classA: This is the classA
- classA: This is the constructor

Both `class?classA` and `?classA` will show `classA-class` help page. This is definitely what I want as I hope `class?classA` will lead to `classA-class: This is the classA` while `?classA` will lead to `classA: This is the constructor`.

So, my question is how to separate the class documentation and constructor documentation with Roxygen2? 
Thank you so much for all your help.

(*I understand that Roxygen2 will put aliases with the class name for S4 class by default. But when I set* `@aliases NULL`, *the* `classA-class: This is the classA` *help page disappeared!! left only the* `classA: This is the constructor`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reasons that both help files show up under the class documentation is that the `setClass` always uses the class name as an alias for the class in the documentation.  In addition, your method for the generic `initialize` defined for `classA` specifies `@rdname classA` which points it to the `classA-method`.

Here are two solutions:

First, you can simplify the Roxygen2 header codes and get the behaviour you want, but you will need to use `@name` to call the initialize method something other than `classA`.

```
#' \code{classA} class definition
#'
#' @slot member description of this slot here
classA <- setClass(Class = "classA", slots = list(member = "ANY"))    

#' constructor for \link{classA-class}
#' 
#' This is the constructor.
#' @name initializeClassA
#' @export
setMethod("initialize", "classA", function(.Object, x) {
    .Object@member = x
    return(.Object)
})
```

That gives you the classA-class page for `?classA` and `?"classA-class"` but for the constructor, you get whatever name you used after `@rdname`, e.g. `?initializeClassA`, if that's what you want.

Second, I would recommend that you not use `initialize` at all, instead create new instances of `classA` using `new("classA", memberValue)`.  You can define a prototype in the class definition to assign default values of `member` if you want, and/or validator functions.  Do you really need a separate help page for the constructor?

Comment: Thank you so much for your useful information, Ken. Actually the S4 class I am trying to build contains 10 different slots and I already give them default values with "prototype". The problem is that my initialization method is a little complicated function which has hundreds of lines... So that's why I am trying to separate them. Anyway as you said, it may be better to combine the help page for initialization method and S4 class together or give a different name to constructor.